# how to transfer the dataframe to json format

Tags: json, dataframe, pyspark

I am wondering how to transfer the pyspark dataframe to json format.

```
name   ㅣ type    
'james'ㅣ 'message'-> 4, 'text' ->3
'kane' ㅣ 'message'->2, 'text'->3
```

----------------------------result--------------------------------

dataframe to json fomat

```
data = [
          {name : 'james', 'message' : 4, 'text; : 3}, {'name' : 'kane', 'message' :2, 'text' : 3}
       ]
```

How to change dataframe to json data?

Comment: is the `type` column schama list of map?

Comment: yes,  type column is list of map !   ex) ['message' -> 3, 'text'->2]

Comment: lol, that was just a map not list haha. my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```scala
 df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()
    /**
      * +-----+-------------------------+
      * |name |type                     |
      * +-----+-------------------------+
      * |james|[message -> 4, text -> 3]|
      * |kane |[message -> 2, text -> 3]|
      * +-----+-------------------------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- name: string (nullable = false)
      * |-- type: map (nullable = false)
      * |    |-- key: string
      * |    |-- value: integer (valueContainsNull = false)
      */

    val p = df.select(to_json(collect_list(map_concat(col("type"), map(lit("name"), $"name")))).as("data"))
    p.show(false)

    /**
      * +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
      * |data                                                                                |
      * +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
      * |[{"message":"4","text":"3","name":"james"},{"message":"2","text":"3","name":"kane"}]|
      * +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
      */
    println(p.head().getString(0))

    /**
      * [{"message":"4","text":"3","name":"james"},{"message":"2","text":"3","name":"kane"}]
      */
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
df.withColumn('data', f.map_concat('map', f.map_from_entries(f.array(f.struct(f.lit('name'), f.col('name')))))) \
  .groupBy().agg(f.collect_list('data').alias('data')) \
  .withColumn('data', f.to_json(f.struct('data'))) \
  .show(10, False)

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|data                                                                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"data":[{"text":"3.0","message":"3.0","name":"kane"},{"message":"4.0","text":"2.0","name":"james"}]}|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```